# Completeness of automorphism groups of free metabelian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I am not very familiar with free metabelian groups, so I apologise in advance if this is trivial.

A group $G$ is said to be *complete* if every automorphism of $G$ is inner. In this case, $\operatorname{Aut}(G) \cong G$ (for centreless groups, this is an equivalent property to being complete). The following classes of groups are known to have complete automorphism groups: f.g. non-abelian free groups [1], f.g. free nilpotent groups of rank $\neq 1,3$ and class $2$ [2], f.g. non-abelian free solvable groups [3].

Hence we have e.g. $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Aut}(F_2)) \cong \operatorname{Aut}(F_2)$, where $F_2$ is the free group of rank $2$.

**Is it known whether every f.g. non-abelian free metabelian group has complete automorphism group?**

Note that Bachmuth [4] showed that the automorphism group of a free metabelian group of rank $>2$ is not metabelian (or solvable), and seemed to indicate that the structure for rank $2$ is somewhat tractable. I am curious if anything further has been shown later.

${}$

**References**

[1] *Dyer, Joan L.; Formanek, Edward*, [**Complete automorphism groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1975-13776-1), Bull. Am. Math. Soc. 81, 435-437 (1975). [ZBL0304.20030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0304.20030).

[2] *Dyer, Joan L.; Formanek, Edward*, [**Automorphism sequences of free nilpotent groups of class two**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100052269), Math. Proc. Camb. Philos. Soc. 79, 271-279 (1976). [ZBL0324.20043](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0324.20043).

[3] *Dyer, Joan L.; Formanek, Edward*, [**Characteristic subgroups and complete automorphism groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2373862), Am. J. Math. 99, 713-753 (1977). [ZBL0367.20041](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0367.20041).

[4] *Bachmuth, S.*, [**Automorphisms of free metabelian groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1993945), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 118, 93-104 (1965). [ZBL0131.02101](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0131.02101).

Comment: I guess that "complete" meant either that $G\to Aut(G)$ is surjective, or that it's bijective, but not just that there exists an isomorphism (in particular I don't think the dihedral groups of order $2^{n\ge 3}$ are viewed as complete. In any case, it's not important here since these are groups with trivial center.

Comment: @YCor Ah yes, you're right, I am really only interested in when $\operatorname{Aut}(G) \cong G$ and mislabelled this property, but as you say it's equivalent here. I've updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: There are several much more recent papers about automorphism groups of metabelian groups.

Comment: @MarkSapir Did you have any particular in mind?

Comment: For your question: see, for example, Roman'kov, V. A. 
Primitive elements and automorphisms of the free metabelian group of rank 3. Sib. Èlektron. Mat. Izv. 17 (2020), 61–76,